# g++ File too short error

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora

I recently opened up a `Fedora 23 vm` and was trying to compile `helloworld` in c++. However, whenever I try compiling using c++, I keep getting this error.

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-5.3.1/cc1plus: error while loading shared 
libraries: /lib64/libmpc.so.3: file too short
```

I looked around for an answer but all the answers said to export a correct path for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or to make sure that `libmpc.so.3` is linked to `libmpc.so.3.0.0`, which it is. I'm at a complete loss as to why this would be happening as I was able to compile on a `Fedora vm` before, just not this particular one, and did not have an error at all.

Comment: Looks like you have a broken installation of g++.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a complete noob, I tried using yum reinstall gcc-c++. Is there a better way to confirm if it's a broken installation?

Comment: You can try installing the -devel libmpc files.
**sudo dnf -y install libmpc-devel**
Also try
**sudo dnf -y install libgcc**
If those don't work, then @SergeyA is probably right, but I have no real idea on how to fix it.